# Lock multiple files in MKS

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

Can someone help me with the command to lock multiple files in MKS.
To lock a single file, the command is `si lock --gui "filepath"`. I have tried some combinations like `si lock --gui "filepath1;filepath2"` and `si lock --gui "filepath1";"filepath2"` but ended up in getting an errormessage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my question:
Use spaces to specify more than one member.

```
si lock --gui "filepath1" "filepath2"
```